# How in feature testing use data from factory?

Tags: laravel-5, factory

In laravel 5.8 app with tests I make posting data with some dummy data, like:

```
$newVoteCategoryRow= [
    'id'   => null,
    'name'   => $new_vote_category_row_name,
    'meta_description'   => 'vote category meta_description on ' . now(),
    'meta_keywords'   => [ 'vote category meta_description on ' . now(), 'meta_keywords' ],
    'active'      => true,
    'in_subscriptions'      => true,
];

$response = $this->actingAs($loggedUser)->post('/admin/vote-categories', $newVoteCategoryRow);
$this->assertCount( $vote_categories_count+1, VoteCategory::all() );
```

it works ok, but actually I have factory for VoteCategory table in /database/factories/VoteCategoryFactory.php, defined :

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use \Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Services\SlugService;
use App\VoteCategory;

$factory->define(App\VoteCategory::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    $name= 'Vote category ' . $faker->word;
    $slug = SlugService::createSlug(VoteCategory::class, 'slug', $name);

    return [
        'name' => $name,
        'slug' => $slug,
        'active' => true,
        'in_subscriptions' => false,
        'meta_description' => $faker->text,
        'meta_keywords' => $faker->words(4),
    ];
});
```

and my question is if there is a way in post request instead of $newVoteCategoryRow array use my factory, not adding row in database but 
reading data from factory for post request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve that you just need to use your factory within the test case method:

to create `VoteCategory` u have to methods, the first one is `make` and this one will create an instance of `VoteCategory` without persisting it within the database, and the `create` method will persist the new `VoteCategory` within the database.

in your case, you want to create a new instance without adding it to the database, for that you just need to use `make`:

```
$newVoteCategoryRow = factory('App\VoteCategory')->make(); // add this line to your test case method.

$response = $this->actingAs($loggedUser)->post('/admin/vote-categories', $newVoteCategoryRow->toArray());

$this->assertCount( $vote_categories_count+1, VoteCategory::all());
```

for more information, you can check the doc [Laravel 5.8: using-factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#using-factories)